# How to create set across JSON (AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "list": [{
            "name": "1",
            "type": ["A", "B"],
        },
        {
            "name": "2",
            "type": ["A", "D", "C"],
        },
        {
            "name": "3",
            "type": ["D", "E"],
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like output a set of types (meaning, unique type values across `list`), like so:

```
Types: A, B, C, D, E
```

I'm trying to do something like

```
<div ng-repeat="element.type in list | unique='type'">
  {{element.type}}
</div>
```

but can't get it quite right. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is wrong? What is the current output, any errors?

Comment: I'm getting different errors, but the point is that I'm not sure this should work at all, so I am looking for the correct way to approach this task. The way I understand it, `unique` works on one `ng-repeat` cycle. Here, I basically want to get the result of a nested `ng-repeat` run, join that, and then get all unique values from that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your indexing is correct, you should use span tags since they are inline elements:

```
<span>Types: </span>

<span ng-repeat="element.type in list | unique='type'">
  {{element.type}}<span ng-if="$index < list.length - 1">,</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it yourself once in the controller, which would also be more performant (filters run quite often):

```
let set = new Set();

list.forEach(el => {
  el.type.forEach(t => {
    set.add(t);
  });
});

$scope.uniqueTypes = Array.from(set);

<span ng-repeat="type in uniqueTypes">
  {{type}}
</span>
```